# Facebook post preview is not showing in shareDialog when applink used as content url using facebooksdk4.2

Tags: android

"a preview will be added after you post this to facebook" is displayed instead of dsiplaying content,image before posting in facebook share dialog when i used an applink, which was set using setContentUrl() using share dialogue of android facebook sdk4.2+.How to fix this issue. Please help me...

used following code snippet for facebook share.....

```
 ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Some title")
                .setContentDescription("some description")
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1782/classic_blue/256/classic_blue_android.png"))
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://fb.me/390376541148098"))
                .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

I have used for my personal content to share on  my facebook wall.

> For setcontentUrl():  I have given a facebook app link which contains a url of my app in playstore.
>
> For setContentDescription : I have  given some text about my app.
>
> setContenttitle() :  It contains text of my app name.
>
> Done all this and tested. then facebook share dialog opened but it consists of thumbnail with message like "a preview will be added after you post this to facebook" instead of showing preview that contains :
>      a image,
>      content description,
>      contenttitle, which makes me worry lot.
>
> but clicked on post . the content is posted as per my requirement well in my fb.

Any body give suggestions to solve this issue...

Comment: not clear, please post your code

Comment: Try the actual content url instead of the shortened url.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got an issue using actual play store url like....the content desription,content title, is replaced with playstore information.so for avoiding this issue i have used facebook app link.which shortened as above for setcontenturl().

Comment: Did you solved the problem?.I am also facing this issue right and I can share the post but the preview of the post is not shown in the share dialog.

Answer (score 1):

From the refference in the facebook docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Note: If your app share links to the iTunes or Google Play stores, we do not post any images or descriptions that you specify in the share. Instead we post some app information we scrape from the app store directly with the Webcrawler. This may not include images. To preview a link share to iTunes or Google Play, enter your URL into the [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).